# How to use Golang Sheriff Package with GORM library?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to use the Golang [Sheriff](https://github.com/liip/sheriff) package with GORM Library somehow I'm getting an empty response. Tried a couple of ways no luck. Any help that would be great. TIA

```
//STRUCT
type Book struct {
    ID        uint `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key" groups:"not_detail,detail"`
    Realname      string `json:"real_name" groups:"not_detail,detail"`
    LanguageId int `json:"language_id" groups:"not_detail,detail"`
    Language   Language `json:"Language" groups:"detail"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" groups:"not_detail,detail"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" groups:"not_detail,detail"`
}
```

```
//CONTROLLER LOGIC
func FindBooks(c *gin.Context)  {
    db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
    var books []models.Book
    result := db.Find(&books)

    o := sheriff.Options{
        Groups: []string{"not_detail"},
    }

    d, err := sheriff.Marshal(&o, result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data":d})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result := db.Find(&books)
```

Here `Find()` return `*DB` means db connection, fetched data is in `books`. So you should send `books` in `sheriff.Marshal`

```
var books []models.Book
db.Find(&books)

o := sheriff.Options{
    Groups: []string{"not_detail"},
}

d, err := sheriff.Marshal(&o, books)
```

Comment: `db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
 var books []models.Book

 o := sheriff.Options{
  Groups: []string{"not_detail"},
 }

 d, err := sheriff.Marshal(&o, db.Find(&books))`
doing like this... but somehow the empty result is coming...

Comment: yes. but I didn't get your point. I was trying to call the find method in Marshal func. but not working..

Comment: Find method doesn't return books data rather send fetched data in Marshal method. I updated answer with full code.